# Why recurse is not working in if statement?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write script which will copy content of files with .txt extension to one. Script is working but -recurse is not. (It dosn't copy files which are in sub folders) and I don't know why is that. This is how my script looks like:

```
function UnifyConfigs {
        param (
        $destination = "C:\temp\all.txt",
        [Parameter()]
        $files
    )
  
    foreach ($config in $files) {
        If((Get-ChildItem $config -Recurse).LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Item $destination).LastWriteTime)
        {
            Clear-Content -path $destination
            Set-Content -path $destination -value (Get-Content $config) 
        }
        else {
            break
        }  
    }
}
```

And yes: I have tried it with -force :-)

Comment: If $config is not a true file path, then there is nothing to recurse.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the call to Get-ChildItem, and why you have -Recurse there? What will be in $config for instance? Can you give some concrete examples?

Comment: Please show us how you call `UnifyConfigs` as well

Comment: This is how I call function : 
UnifyConfigs -files C:\PowerShell\*.txt

Comment: $files- will be a directory (as it is shown above) from which all files *.txt should be taken. And $config is individual file from path $files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, you need to move the `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` call to where you resolve the input string to actual files in the filesystem:

```
foreach ($config in Get-ChildItem $files -Recurse) {
    if($config.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Item $destination).LastWriteTime)
    {
        Clear-Content -path $destination
        Set-Content -path $destination -value (Get-Content $config) 
    }
    else {
        break
    }  
}
```

If you just want to test that *any* of the input files are newer than the destination file and then overwrite the contents of the destination with *all* of the other txt files, that actually becomes a tad simpler - we can discard the outer loop completely:

```
# Discover all the files
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem $files -Recurse

# use `-gt` and the destination timestamp to "filter" all the config file timestamps
# if _any_ of them are newer that $destination, then the condition is true
if(@($configFiles.LastWriteTime) -gt (Get-Item $destination).LastWriteTime){
    # pipe every file to Get-Content, and then overwrite $destination with the whole thing
    $configFiles |Get-Content |Set-Content -Path $destination -Force
}
```

I'd also recommend refactoring the parameter names to better reflect what the expected input is ("C:\path\to*files" is a string representing a "path", it is not "files"):

```
function Update-UnifiedConfig {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$DestinationPath = "C:\temp\all.txt",

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Path
    )

    $destinationLastModified = (Get-Item -LiteralPath $DestinationPath).LastWriteTime

  $configFiles = Get-ChildItem $files -Recurse

  if(@($configFiles.LastWriteTime) -gt $destinationLastModified){
    $configFiles |Get-Content |Set-Content -LiteralPath $DestinationPath -Force
  }
}
```

The reason I'm using `-LiteralPath` in most places above is because `$DestinationPath` is just that, `-Path` on the other hand will treat wildcards as *expandable* which is only appropriate for the `$Path` parameter value in this function

Comment: Thanks, but it looks that in this configuration 
`foreach ($config in Get-ChildItem $files -Recurse)` is not working at all :/ Unfortunately there is no error so it is hard for me to verify what can be wrong .

Comment: @Patrycja Does it work if you try executing it manually in the prompt? Ie. does `Get-ChildItem C:\PowerShell*.txt -Recurse` return anything?

Comment: yes, it shows all files which are in this path including one which is in sub folder

Comment: Then it's not for the `foreach()` statement that's the problem, but the `if/else` statement inside - if the first file it encounters is _older_ than `$DestinationPath`, then it'll enter the `else` block and `break` out of the loop - maybe add a `Write-Host $config.FullName` statement at the top of both the `if` and `else` blocks if you want a visual indication of what is going on.

Comment: It looks that you are right but still script doesn't work as required. Now I can see that it detect modification date of file in sub folder but it doesn't take content of it. I would imagine that it will take content of all *.txt  files in `$files` if any of them was modify later then `$DestinationPath`

Comment: @Patrycja So, if _any_ of the files have been modified more recently than `$DestinationPath`, then you want to overwrite `$DestinationPath` with the concatenated contents of all the other txt files? Is that correctly understood?

Comment: exactly! this is what I want.... What is wrong with my script ? :/

Comment: @Patrycja Ahh, then the logic error in your original example makes a lot more sense! Everything makes more sense :) I've updated the answer

Comment: Well, I tried to run script with `$configFiles |Get-Content |Set-Content -Path $destination -Force` but even that I call it as : `Update-UnifiedConfig -path C:\Powershell` it was checking all files I don't know from where (I could see some proxy set up etc) . I don't know if it is because I simply copy-paste it to my VS code or if something is wrong it script itself . On first look I don't see any reason why it  can be failing but I will investigate it more.